# How to automatic update records in a row?

Tags: php

I have a problem on how to update all status in one click.

As you can see in the picture bellow, if I click the lock it should automatically update all statuses of the students to "lock", if I click the unlock button it should set it to "unlock", how to do that?

[image: this is the image]

Here's my code:

```
<a href="unlock.php"  title="Lock"><img src="images/lock.png" height="40" width="40"></a>

<a href="lock.php" title="Unlock"><img style="margin-left:8px;" src="images/unlock.png" height="40" width="40"></a>
```

when I click the lock.php here's what my codes like:

```
include '../connection/connect.php';
include '../dbcon.php';

$idnum=$_POST['idnum'];
$stat='LOCK';
$sqla = "UPDATE student 
         SET status=?
         WHERE idno=?";
$qa = $db->prepare($sqla);
$qa->execute(array($stat,$idnum));

Header('Location:lock_unlock.php');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: I've put what I've done

Comment: You have a single Lock image but more than one person displayed. How can one ID links to 10 different people/department. Re-think the design

Comment: When I click lock all student will update their status into="lock"

Comment: What all student on the database? Not according to your SQL Query

Comment: yes, how to put an sql to update all student?

Comment: `UPDATE student SET status=?`

Comment: that's what I put in the lock.php but it doesn't work

Comment: No you have a WHERE clause on your Query

Comment: You are also not passing a `idnum` param so `WHERE idno=?` will convert to either `WHERE idno=` or `WHERE idno=null` neither of which can exist

Comment: ok, sir I got it thank you with love sir :) really appreciated

Comment: and if it's in a link (<a>) then it'll be a $_GET, not a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your query to be like:

```
$sqla = "UPDATE student 
         SET status=?;
```

You do not need where clause as you want to update all of them.